# jQuery: Find specific number & replace with specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a food menu in my website.
In my food menu you can select what you want with your meat.

For example:

```
shawarma: pita:10$ Baguette:12$ Plate: 17$
steak: pita: 20 Baguette:none Plate:35$
```

the problem is when some of the menu items dont have one of the pita or Baguette or Plate, the script will print zero "0"

```
steak: pita: 20 Baguette:0 Plate:35$
```

I am trying to Find all the `0` number and replace with `-`.
the problem is that in some items the price come with `0` like `10`, `20`, `30`, etc...
here i don't want to change the "0" to "-"

I tried to use this code: (but this code not makes me what i need)

Any suggestions?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("div").find(":contains('0')").each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $this.text("-");
    });
});
```

the html looks:

```
<div id="wppizza-article-tiers-118" class="wppizza-article-tiers">


                    <span id="wppizza-118-4-0" class="wppizza-article-price ">
                <span>0 $</span>
                                <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Toast</div>
                            </span>
                    <span id="wppizza-118-4-1" class="wppizza-article-price ">
                <span>20 $</span>
                                <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Big Pita</div>
                            </span>
                    <span id="wppizza-118-4-2" class="wppizza-article-price ">
                <span>33 $</span>
                                <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Baguette</div>
                            </span>
                    <span id="wppizza-118-4-3" class="wppizza-article-price ">
                <span>35 $</span>
                                <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">לאפה</div>
                            </span>
                    <span id="wppizza-118-4-4" class="wppizza-article-price ">
                <span>49 $</span>
                                <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Plate</div>
                            </span>


        </div>
```

Comment: can you show us the html code?

Comment: Hi @VDesign i have add html

Comment: Please checkout the answers below and mark one as accepted that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Regular Expression with `.replace()` will do that: `/\b0\b/g`

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var myString = "steak: pita: 20 Baguette:0 Plate:35$";

myString = myString.replace("/\b0\b/g", "-");

alert(myString);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6j0543/)

Readup: [`.replace()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

---

**EDIT:**

Try this for your HTML code:

```
$('#wppizza-article-tiers-118 span span').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.replace(/\b0\b/g, "-");
  $(this).text(text);
});
```

**Regex Explained:**

```
/\b0\b/g
```

Here,
`/` is what your regex pattern is enclosed in.
`\b` means boundary.
`0` is what you actually need to replace.
`g` means global. The replacement will be done globally.

[Various Regex tutorials | Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Regex+tutorials&oq=Regex+tutorials&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

---

**EDIT2:** Here is the **working code snippet** for the HTML in your question.

```js
$('.wppizza-article-price span').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.replace(/\b0\b/g, "-");
  $(this).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wppizza-article-tiers-118" class="wppizza-article-tiers">


  <span id="wppizza-118-4-0" class="wppizza-article-price ">
    <span>0 $</span>
    <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Toast</div>
  </span>
  <span id="wppizza-118-4-1" class="wppizza-article-price ">
    <span>20 $</span>
    <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Big Pita</div>
  </span>
  <span id="wppizza-118-4-2" class="wppizza-article-price ">
    <span>33 $</span>
    <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Baguette</div>
  </span>
  <span id="wppizza-118-4-3" class="wppizza-article-price ">
    <span>35 $</span>
    <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">לאפה</div>
  </span>
  <span id="wppizza-118-4-4" class="wppizza-article-price ">
    <span>49 $</span>
    <div class="wppizza-article-price-lbl wppizza-no-cart">Plate</div>
  </span>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul Desai, how can i use your code with $("div").each(function()? you can see my html i have add.

Comment: @user2413244 If you checkout **EDIT2** in my answer above, I have demonstrated my jQuery code with your HTML. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @user2413244 Make sure that you understand it. :) Feel free to ask any questions that you might have.

Comment: one more thing @Rahul Desai, when we replace the "0" with the "-" the "$" is stay. can we replace 0 $ with "-" and not just "0"?

Comment: @user2413244 Sure, just replace the regex with `/\b0\s\$/g`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wppizza-article-price").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).find('span').text();
        if (value == '0 $') {
           $(this).find('span').text('-'); 
        }
    });
 });
```

it will work now  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6j0543/2/)

Comment: Hi @Mohamed-Yousef your code do the same as mine. it remove all my menu items where is "0" and print "-" so all html gons